# Why does Typescript infer a different type inside setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, typescript, settimeout

The following snippet gives me a type error:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(!dragWrapperRef || !dragWrapperRef.current) return;
   setTimeout(() => {
      setDragWrapperHeight(dragWrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px');
   },500);
},[]);
```

> current: HTMLDivElement | null.  'dragWrapperRef.current' is possibly 'null'.

```
const dragWrapperRef: RefObj | null = useRef(null);
```

```
type RefObj = {
    current: HTMLDivElement | null
}
```

The type for dragWrapperRef is correctly inferred if I use `dragWrapperRef.current` outside of setTimeout. This does not throw an error:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(!dragWrapperRef || !dragWrapperRef.current) return;
   setDragWrapperHeight(dragWrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px')
},[]);
```

It does work inside setTimeout if I assign the ref object to another variable outside of the setTimeout *((property) current: HTMLDivElement)*:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(!dragWrapperRef || !dragWrapperRef.current) return;
   const el = dragWrapperRef.current;

   setTimeout(() => {
       setDragWrapperHeight(el.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px')
   },1000);
},[]);
```

Why is the type not recognized inside the scope of setTimeout if I pass it in directly – but behaves correctly if assigned to another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because things could have changed in the half-second between when you did the checks and the time the timer fires. (In the more general case: TypeScript doesn't try to track type narrowing of properties/variables that can change into callbacks. This is just a specific example.)

To avoid the error, you *could* assign to a local `const` (but keep reading):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const current = dragWrapperRef?.current;
    if (current) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setDragWrapperHeight(current.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px");
        }, 500);
    }
}, []);
```

...but TypeScript is right, in the half-second between grabbing the value and the timer callback running, the ref could have changed! Meaning the code would be using an out-of-date ref. Since that's the case, you might want to just repeat the check:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (dragWrapperRef?.current) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const current = dragWrapperRef?.current;
            if (current) {
                setDragWrapperHeight(current.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px");
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}, []);
```